# Change the "add a comment" link text?

Tags: discussion, comments

There is an active [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299195) on meta.SE by one of the Community Managers, proposing to **change** the ***add a comment*** text below each post to something that better conveys the [intended usage of comments](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) on Stack Exchange.

<sub>Current text ([source](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33168)):</sub>

[image: ugh!]

The change on Area 51 uses "suggest improvements" for answers, and "ask for clarification" on questions:

[image: ask for clarification]

[image: Area 51 screenshot]

[image: show more...]

In summary:

- Change "add comment" under the **question** to "ask for clarification"
- Change "add comment" under the **answer** to "suggest improvements"

There is a [separate idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256969) to provide a second link below each post, linking to a chat room for more general discussion about the Q & A, but that is out of scope for this meta question.

Thinking just about the **"add a comment" link**, what do you think would be a good replacement for our site?

Or is this a terrible idea, and we should just leave it as-is?

Comment: Interesting, these changes might help to reduce superfluous comments. In my opinion, someone may like to "ask for clarification" with respect to answers as well. Regarding questions, the "suggest improvements" point would suggest something close to the *edit* option, where a user can actually "make the improvement".

Comment: As for questions, the "ask for clarification" label could also guide the OP in clarifying directly in the question body instead of doing it via comments (another common problem that entails extra work).

Comment: The drawback on changing from **add a comment** to anything else is the question from @RDFozz regarding [Commenting on questions you don't intend to answer](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2811/15356) (slightly). You might not be asking for clarification, but adding a tidbit of information on what you thing might be a solution. This happens before there is an answer.

Comment: @hot2use Yes well that's one of the current uses of "comments" we want to discourage - see my answer on that question for my reasoning. People will still do it, of course, just maybe less often?

Comment: @PaulWhite Regarding questions, there are times when, for example, instead of supplying an answer one uses comments to post a link to a Q & A which (1) does not directly answer the question at hand but that (2) can be used to establish an analogy with que scenario under consideration to solve the problem. So:

Comment: That would certainly not qualify as "asking for clarification". Should that kind of action be frowned upon? Could it be considered "answering questions in comments"? I think this point has a connection with the aspects discussed in these meta posts, even if the labels for comments remain the same.

Comment: @MDCCL We allow those because they're often useful (e.g. when the link is same-site, it appears in the Linked/Related list. There will always be edge cases, so don't worry too much about always matching the wording in an exact sense.

Comment: Makes sense, they can help the OP and a future visitor.

Answer (score 6):

Change it to "suggest improvements" on **answers** and "ask for clarification" on **questions** because...

Answer (score 2):

Change it to “suggest improvements or ask for clarification” for **answers** and “ask for clarification” for **questions** because...

- Someone may like to “ask for clarification” with respect to answers as well.
- Regarding questions, the “suggest improvements” point would suggest something close to the “edit” option, through which a user can actually “make the improvement”, so it's not necessary.
- As for questions, the “ask for clarification” label could also assist in other common problems. For example, it may:

  - guide the OP in clarifying directly in the question body instead of doing it via comments
  - reduce occurrences of answers posted by means of the comment box

Comment: One can suggest the improvement that the answer needs to be clearer about something.

Comment: Definitely, and one can as well ask for clarification about a certain aspect; for example: "What does point *x* mean exactly?". These changes might not be as precise as one would wish, but I consider that they can help to diminish the current abuse/misuse of the comment facilities.

Comment: Very good point and probably even the better solution. I can't remove my vote for the other answer until it's edited but I like this way of wording better

Comment: @TomV Let's see if someone shares other ideas. This proposal can be improved of course.

Answer (score 1):

Leave it as "add a comment" because...

...The drawback on changing from **add a comment** to anything else is the question from [@RDFozz](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/116653/rdfozz) regarding [Commenting on questions you don't intend to answer](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2811/15356) (slightly). You might not be asking for clarification, but adding a tidbit of information on what you think might be a solution. This happens before there is an answer.

Comment: "Adding a tidbit of information on what you think might be a solution" would qualify as asking for clarification, in my opinion.

Comment: @RDFozz The way I see it, a solution qualifies as an answer (maybe a partial one) not as a clarification request, so it should be better posted as a community wiki answer, perhaps.

Comment: Currently, the background of the comment box tells: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments".

Comment: We tell new users not to provide answers that require additional clarification from the asker. Just trying to follow that same principal by asking questions.

Answer (score -2):

Change it to "suggest improvements" for **both** answers and questions, because...